# How to get a System.__ComObject value from Active Directory in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, comobject

After a long period of search I decide to ask my own question about my problem.

I try to get the value of a Property in Active Directory, but I always get a **System.__ComObject**.

```
correspondance += compte.Properties["ENTPersonDateNaissance"][0];
```

I have tried to use :

```
 Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(compte.Properties["ENTPersonDateNaissance"]
```

The result is **PropertyValueCollection**

But I don't know how to get the value?

Comment: Can you share what type of values you are expecting from the property? It's because the property value is represented using the ADSI IADsLargeInteger COM interface.

Comment: What does this property represent? I cant find it in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the variable "compte" is of type DirectoryEntry, I switched it to SearchResult, and now I can access it value with :

```
compte.Properties["ENTPersonDateNaissance"][0].ToString()
```

I hope it can help.

Comment: Hey i am having similar problem. can you help?

Comment: My object "compte" was a DirectoryEntry and I don't figure out but when I use the SearchResult instead of the SerarchResult.GetDirectoryEntry I can access the value that I want to get. Hope this can help